# Stored procedure with multiple tables with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I am working on an event management project. In that project, I have a form in admin panel as add event which contains events name, category, sub-category, event admin etc and more. And in the database, I have different tables like event category, event sub-category.

And also I have a table that is cultural event which includes form fields and foreign key. I pass event catid, event sub-cat id.

On button click that cultural event is added.

I want to insert data in their tables and I want id that I gave in cultural event table.

On single click I want to insert this

How can I achieve this? Using a stored procedure?

CREATE TABLE EVENT_SCAT (ESUBCAT_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ECAT_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EVENT_CAT(ECAT_ID), ESUBCAT_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, )

create table EVENT_CAT (ECAT_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ECAT_NAME VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL, EID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EVENTDETAILS(EID)

CREATE TABLE Cultural_E (c_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, cEVENT_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, cE_SDATE DATE NOT NULL, cE_EDATE DATE NOT NULL, SE_RULES1 VARCHAR(MAX), SE_RULES2 VARCHAR(MAX), SE_RULES3 VARCHAR(MAX), cE_RULES4 VARCHAR(MAX), cE_EFEES INT, EID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EVENTDETAILS(EID), ECAT_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EVENT_CAT(ECAT_ID) )

and i have form in asp.net which includes all fields in single form but there are different tables with foreign keys. and i want id of ecat id and subcatid in last table i.e Cultural_e.

for ex:THESE ARE TABLE

eVENT_T

ID        ENAME        EADMIN

1       CULTURAL        NIKHIL

E_CAT

ID      ECAT_NAME         E_iD

1       SINGING           1

event_scat

ID      eCAT_iD      ESUBCAT_NAME

1         1               SOLO

NOW I HAVE TABLE THAT IS CULTURAL_T

THESE TABLE HAVE ITS OWN FILEDS AS WELL AS FOREIGN KEY LIKE EID ,ECAT_ID AS YOU CAN SEE ABOVE

AND I HAVE FORM IN ASP.NET AND FORM CONTAINS TEXTBOX TO ENTER DATA OF ALL THESE TABLE.

SO PLZ TELL ME HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS

THANK YOU

Comment: Your post could use some punctuation and clarification... but I assume you are just needing to join a few tables to insert their ID values into another table. That is possible with a sproc. What RDBMS are you using? If you provide a better data structure and your expected output someone can reply with the SQL you will need to do the insert.

Comment: i am using Sql server.see i have table event_category event sub category and cultural event.cultural table have foreign key even category id and sub category id. i want event cat and sub cat id on single click

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question,try to use triggers rather than stored procedures if possible.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertEvents
AFTER INSERT ON EVENT_CAT
BEGIN
    /* Insert Query to EVENT_SCAT */
    /* Insert Query to cultural */
END
```

Comment: can you explain with simple example by using triggers?please

Comment: can you explain design of the tables ? I am not getting it. Is cat id and sub cat id are static ( fixed values ) ?

Comment: Try Above type of trigger.

Comment: @NikhilBhoite: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: i am sorry...i am new here....and thanks marc_s and rajdeep. but one more thing. i want id of subcat and cat in cultural table. how to achieve this

Comment: In case you can see how the trigger works and it syntax for accessing attributes using `NEW` or `OLD` keyword.